# Windows GUI administration tool for MySQL that support 2FA

Tags: gui, mysql, ssh, two-factor-authentication

I'm looking for an alternative to HeidiSQL, Sequel Pro (OSX) or Navicat (software with GUI to manage MySQL database) on Windows that support SSH Tunnel with Two factor authentication.

I've actually tried HeidiSQL and MySQL WorkBench but they don't support 2FA..

Comment: It seems that it doesn't exists ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who stumbles across this question.

I am actually looking at this same issue myself, per my boss wants GUI access for our database for himself and the developers at my company. I have found that Jetbrain's [Datagrip](https://www.jetbrains.com/datagrip/whatsnew/) works for 2FA (key and Google Auth, in my case), albeit it was initially a little bit finicky to actually get the auth codes through and connected.

I do not know what pricing options Jetbrain has for Datagrip since I have access already through our PHPStorm subscription. As well, I myself haven't really used the tool beyond connecting to the DB and describing tables, so I do not know how robust it is and if this particular GUI will actually fit my dev teams needs.

As an aside, the only other viable solution I have found for having 2FA compliance would be moving my Google auth off of the server and into [a remote VPN solution](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-technical-content/latest/aws-vpc-connectivity-options/software-remote-access-vpn-internal-user.html).